# Перевод 16581375 байт в мегабайты

Tags: информация

Гугл при запросе "16581375 байт в мегабайты" почему-то выдёт "16 581 375 байт = 16.581375 десятичных мегабайта", хотя 16581375/1024=16192мб

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все правильно у вас в килобайтах, надо еще раз на 1024 (16581375/1024/1024)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что мегабайты не равны мебибайтам. Смотри про двоичные приставки.